# (Newbies) Deep learning Binary Classification problems

Tags: python, tensorflow

Due to Input of DL must be float so if I have a dataset containing Customer_ID(Object) like A1001, B1001 and all features are 0/1

How do I skip this Customer_ID column to avoid float() error on TensorFlow in fit() function?

Comment: How do you store the data. Pandas?

Comment: yes sir pd.read_csv('xxx.csv')

Comment: I want to ignore CUSTOMER_ID column to feed data into a model by not touching whole dataset ?

Comment: `.drop(columns=['Customer_ID'])` on the pandas dataframe

Comment: so I need to drop the column only ? Is there any solution to mark this column as metadata and let deep learning skip that column for making the model?

Comment: the column won't disappear, unless you do it like `df = df.drop(...)`. You can just call the `fit(df.drop(...))`, and the column will still remain in `df` untouched